# Derivative of $\text{Tr}(A B^{1/2})$ w.r.t. matrix $B$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace

Similar but more complicated questions have been asked, but I am simply interested in the gradient:$$\nabla_B \text{Tr}(A B^{1/2})$$ for positive-definite, symmetric $B$ ($A$ can be also assumed to be square, symmetric, positive-definite, if it leads to a computable derivative). Here $(\cdot)^{1/2}$ denotes the matrix square-root.

Is there a simple formula for this?

Answers to the existing questions look complicated and I am not sure if there's a closed form expression clearly in terms of $B$ so one can actually code it up, not only theoretically find the expression. And perform things like gradient descent.

Thanks.

PS: The specific gradient I am interested in looks like this: $$\nabla_B \text{Tr}\left((A^{1/2} B A^{1/2})^{1/2}\right).$$ I asked above for simplicity, but maybe this specific structure makes things easier.

Comment: If $A$ _**commutes**_ with $B$ (as it does in your second case) then the gradient equals $\,\frac{1}{2}A^TB^{-1/2}$

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by the second case? Even if $A,B$ are symmetric, positive-definite in general, I do not believe that implies commutativity. Note that the second derivative I asked doesn't involve a Trace nor any $A$, but I am more interested in the first.

Comment: You are correct, commutivity  is not implied by the SPD property, but unfortunately it's what's needed for a closed form solution. As for the second case, I initially saw a trace that isn't there. Oops!  An immediate problem with your second case is that the gradient is a 4th order tensor, not a matrix.

Comment: ok, maybe this helps. The specific structure I have is to find $\nabla_B \text{Tr}\left((A^{1/2} B A^{1/2})^{1/2}\right)$. I edited the question. But this does not help with commutativity I guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For typing convenience, define 
$$X = A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$$
Write the objective function in terms of this new variable. Then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= {\rm Tr}(X^{1/2}) \cr
d\phi
 &= \tfrac{1}{2}(X^{-1/2})^T:dX \cr
 &= \tfrac{1}{2}(X^{-1/2})^T:A^{1/2}dB\,A^{1/2} \cr
 &= \tfrac{1}{2}(A^{1/2}X^{-1/2}A^{1/2})^T:dB \cr
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial B}
 &= \frac{1}{2}(A^{1/2}X^{-1/2}A^{1/2})^T \cr
}$$
Since $(A,B)$ are both symmetric, the gradient can be simplified
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial B} &= \frac{1}{2}A^{1/2}X^{-1/2}A^{1/2} \cr
}$$
The colon $(:)$ is a convenient inline product notation for the trace, i.e. 
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
The properties of the trace allow terms in this product to be rearranged in many ways
$$\eqalign{
A:BC &= B^TA:C &= AC^T:B \cr
A:B &= A^T:B^T &= B:A \cr
}$$

Comment: Hi, Thanks! Does this mean the simplification I thought I made $\nabla_B \text{Tr}\left((A^{1/2} B^{1/2} B^{1/2} A^{1/2})^{1/2}\right) = \nabla_B \text{Tr}(A^{1/2} B^{1/2})$ wasn't true? If so, would you tell me what's the problem with it?

Comment: Your simplification is not true because matrix multiplication does not commute. For example, if $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$ then $$\eqalign{(ABC)^{\alpha}&\ne A^{\alpha}B^{\alpha}C^{\alpha}\cr(ABC)^{\alpha}&\ne C^{\alpha}B^{\alpha}A^{\alpha}}$$ While matrix products within a trace function can undergo cyclic rotation, you must apply the fractional power **_before_** applying the cyclic rule.

Comment: Looking more closely at your simplification, it appears you applied the cyclic rule _inside_ of the square root operation, i.e. $(A^\alpha B^\alpha B^\alpha A^\alpha)^\alpha=(A^\alpha A^\alpha B^\alpha B^\alpha)^\alpha$. Then you distributed the fractional power to each matrix $(AB)^\alpha=A^\alpha B^\alpha$. Neither of these manipulations is valid for matrices. And the presence of the trace function does not change that. Note that the trace function doesn't even allow for the following $${\rm Tr}(ABC)\ne{\rm Tr}(ACB)$$ It only allows _cyclic_ rotations of a chain of matrix products.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I see the mistake clearly now! There is an invalid commutation there.